# How to call a method of a class into another class in apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com

I want to use a method of a class onto another class.

```
     eg: public class controller 1{
          public void method 1(){}
      }


     public class controller 2{
         public void method 2() { }     
       }
```

I want to use method1 in class controller2.
Please help me to find the solution on it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use two approaches:

1.Use Static methods

You cannot use controller2 instance methods here

```
public class controller2 
{
    public static string method2(string parameter1, string parameter2) {
        // put your static code in here            
        return parameter1+parameter2;
    }
    ...
}
```

In a separate class file call method2()

```
// this is your page controller
public class controller1
{
    ...
    public void method1() {
        string returnValue = controller2.method2('Hi ','there');
    }
}
```

2.Create an instance of the other class

```
public class controller2 
{
    private int count;
    public controller2(integer c) 
    {
        count = c;
    }

    public string method2(string parameter1, string parameter2) {
        // put your static code in here            
        return parameter1+parameter2+count;
    }
    ...
}

public class controller1
{
    ...
    public void method1() 
    {
        controller2 con2 = new controller2(0);
        string returnValue = con2.method2('Hi ','there');
    }
}
```

If your methods are in a package with a namespace

```
string returnValue = mynamespace.controller2.method2();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by instantiating the class you're calling.

```
// source class
public class MyClass1 {

    public MyClass1() {} // constructor

    public void MyMethod1() {
        // method code
    }
}

// calling class
public class MyClass2 {

    public void MyMethod2() {
        // call MyMethod1 from MyClass1
        MyClass1 c = new MyClass1(); // instantiate MyClass1
        c.MyMethod1();
    }
}
```

Note that if the source class was global (instead of public) and its method was a Web Service, you could also reference it directly using `MyClass1.MyMethod1();`.